# Footer no final do template depois do scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá gostaria de organizar as páginas de um projeto de forma que o footer apareça sempre depois que rolem a página pra baixo.

[image: Footer no meio do template]

Como podem ver, está aparecendo o footer na parte de baixo do template.

Consegui colocar ele para baixo usando css da seguinte forma:

```
html,
body,
header,
.view {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Porém, quando a página se extende muito para baixo, o footer fica na frente do conteúdo.

Comment: não conseguimos te ajudar se você não postar códigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faz o seguinte:

Imagine q vc tem um conteúdo e um rodapé em seu projeto para o conteúdo utilize uma div com a css

```
min-height:100vh;
```

sendo assim esta div ocupara toda altura da tela e logo apos o rodapé irá aparecer ao dar o scrool

Comment: Cara, resolveu meu problema. Valeu!!

Answer (score 0):

Sem detalhes de código fica difícil de propôr soluções, mas se entendi corretamente, o seu problema ocorre somente quando se atinge o final da página, com esse footer ficando à frente do trecho final do conteúdo. Uma solução rápida é adicionar no próprio template algumas linhas em branco (ou um DIV com height específico) na parte final, para "empurrar" qualquer conteúdo para cima da área coberta pelo footer.